# Include WebRTC in iOS project

Tags: ios, linker-errors, webrtc, undefined-symbol, apprtcdemo

I trying to deal with the AppRTCDemo projet but I am getting error.
Which library I forget to include ?

Log error :

`Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCVideoRenderer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in VideoView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCSessionDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCICECandidate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCVideoCapturer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCPair", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCMediaConstraints", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCPeerConnectionFactory", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCICEServer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in APPRTCAppClient.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Thanks

Comment: Please refer to my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803516/iphone-sdk-webrtc-integration-error/25530474#25530474

Regards,

S.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to set the "Other Linker Flags" in the build setting of your project to $(inherited).

Then it will be an inherited link options from the workspace.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this library isn't built for armv7s processors.

Is it static lib built in .a file?

If so, you can run in console `lipo -info` command to see what architectures is this library built for.

For example, this command for some library somelib.a `lipo -info somelib.a` gives output:

```
Architectures in the fat file: somelib.a are: armv7 i386
```

If armv7s architecture isn't supported, but armv7 is, you can also run your project, try setting this in your build options:

"Build Active Architecture Only" YES --> NO.

Comment: Same problem after set "Build Active Architecture Only" YES to NO.

Answer (score 0):

You may be testing on iPhone 5 or above which is on armv7s architecture (see http://iossupportmatrix.com/ for more info).

The AppRTCDemo was built on armv7, that assume to run it on devices issued between the iPhone 3GS and the iPad mini (that includes iPhone 4 and 4s).

Regards,

S.

Answer (score 0):

you have to run the app in ios device....not in simulator